# How can I lock my Gallery Vault on an external SD-card?

Tags: external-sd, gallery-vault

My Gallery Vault was saved on an external memory card. Now my phone is lost.

Can someone access my Gallery Vault which was on the external memory card?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the files are in a hidden folder but a brilliant person can always get them by unhiding and renaming the photos to jpg. The app doesn't encrypt them. It just hides and renames... So there's nothing you can do to stop this other than hoping he formats the sd